# How to count elements on web page?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

1. Open one web page say gmail.
2. Want to count that how many text field or buttons or checkbox or hyperlinks or other html elements are present.

Comment: Like it says in the tag excerpt: When using this tag, also add a tag for the language you're using.

Comment: sry can't understand can you plz give me an example?

Comment: PHP, Java, Python, Ruby, C#

Comment: @Barmar In Java and yeah actually I want that when my driver open the gmail page page then all the number of elements which locate on that page it shows like if it contain two text field then it shows "Text field: 2".

Answer (score 2):

The solution is very simple . This can be done using simple XPath.

Find the type of element count you need. 
eg for text fields: xpath can be : input[type='text']

for radio buttons: xpath can be : //input[@type='radio']

for check box buttons: xpath can be : //input[@type='checkbox']

so find all the elements in the page by using simple command using the above xpath:

```
webdriver.findElements(By.xpath("REQUIRED_XPATH")).size();
```

will give you the number of elements in the particular web page.

Comment: By this we have to give xpath for each web elements, what I want that when my driver open the gmail page page then all the number of elements which locate on that page it shows like if it contain two text field then it shows "Text field: 2", "Button: 1", "Hyperlink: 2" etc.

Comment: Then use CssSelector and pass target tags. That's the easiest way

Answer (score 1):

I am using c#. If you use c# as well the followings is the something you want to use. And you decide what tags you need inside the selector. I am using all the tags so far.

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> webElements = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("input, select, textarea, a, button"))//and keep adding

//then do a simple count. The trick here is the selector and you need to make sure you are adding all the tag names are being used in your application
webElements.Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count all elements of a page, you can simply use * for that as shown below.

```
List<WebElement> items = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("*"));

System.out.println(items);
```

Comment: please check my above comment, actually i don't want to call all the string individually, is there any method or anyway to find it?

Comment: I could not get you.. Can you explain

Comment: my question is how to count the number of elements "Text field", "Check box", "Hyperlinks" etc present in one web page??? But it would be better if we can find all this in one line code instead of creating different object for each elements.

Comment: Whats that "etc" mean? You have any specific set of tags to be verified?

Comment: etc means etcetera....
Now please help to solve my problem. I have just wrote each and every thing which i want.

Comment: I am aware of etc :) My question was wat elements come under that etc?

Comment: Oh ok :) actually I am try it for gmail login page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to know instantly how many items in the list on the website, for example, languages in the wiki, using right-click "Inspect element".

Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]